# Laravel Yajra Datatables [object Object],[object Object] Error

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

Recording data in array format to database workers column. I would then return this data in the appropriate JSON format. My problem is just getting the **spname** values ​​from the **nested array** in the workers column and showing it in the datatables field view. My codes are as follows.

Api controller

```
public function apiZimmet()
    {
        /*
         test... ok it works
        $wdata=Zimmet::first();
        $workers = json_decode($wdata->workers , true);
        foreach($workers as $key => $value) {
                echo $value['spname']."<br>";
            }
        */

        $data = Zimmet::with('proje:id,name');
        return Datatables::eloquent($data)
        ->editColumn('workers', function ($data) {
            $workers = json_decode($data->workers , true);
            return $workers;
        })
        ->addColumn('action', function ($data) {
                return '<ul class="header-dropdown m-r--5">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                        <li>
                        <a href="/system/stok-personeli/'.$data->id.'/edit" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Edit">Duzenle</a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>';
            })->make(true);

    }
```

Return API file is below

```
"data":[         
    {
        "id":"12",
        "name":"test",
        "sicil_no":"1234",
        "proje_id":"1",
        "visible":0,
        "workers":[
            {
            "spid":"1",
            "spsicil":"35678909",
            "spname":"ok"
            },
            {
            "spid":"6",
            "spsicil":"123456",
            "spname":"sdsf sdfsdf"
            }
        ],
        "deleted_at":null,
        "created_at":"2020-04-02 23:29:23",
        "updated_at":"2020-04-02 23:29:23",
        "proje":{
            "id":"1",
            "name":"deneme"
        },
        "action":"edit"
    }
],
```

**in view file ajax**

```
ajax: {
    url: '{{route('api.zimmet')}}',
    method: 'POST'
},
columns: [
    {data: 'id', name: 'id', visible:false, searchable:false},
    {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
    {data: 'sicil_no', name: 'sicil_no'},
    {data: 'proje.name', name: 'proje.name'},
    {data: 'workers', name: 'workers'},
    {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
],
```

When I call the workers column here, gives [object Object],[object Object] error. What I want is to show the spname values ​​in workers in the view file.

Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `workers` is actually an array of objects, you will get exactly that (the object names) if you use `data: 'workers'`.

Datatables has support for this situation, using its [array bracket syntax](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects_subarrays.html). So, for example you can do this:

```
{data: 'workers[, ].spname', name: 'workers'},
```

Using your data, this will print out `ok, sdsf sdfsdf` in the table cell. It iterates through all the `spname` items, and separates them with a comma followed by a space.

If you want something more elaborate, you may need to pre-process your JSON - for example, to flatten it. But the above may be sufficient for your needs.